# Check for text (email ID) in 32-bit binary file?

Tags: linux, security, embedded-linux

Just looking for any pointers (hints) on how I would look for hidden text (basically 1 or multiple email ID's) in a binary file ? The file is compiled for a ELF Linux target. Ideally, I would like to reverse engineer the process but to start I am looking is to find hidden emails in the binary?

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1m3mre0gQQod8TT8U6naa5eS7fbDYZQaU/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Hi Steve, I think you are doing the same code challenge as me. I was able to figure it out by decompiling the binary (either to ASM or C) and examining the main function. I don't want to spoil the fun, but keep a look out for a series of 8 bit dwords going to an array. These aren't ASCII characters but can be converted to such. I used Hopper to decompile the file (I found viewing it in ASM was easier than C...but I know ASM a bit better than C)

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the GNU `strings` command line program:

```
strings <FILE> | grep '@'
```

Comment: Hi - thanks for your quick response. I did try this earlier which gives me an email with `keld@dkuug.dk` but that's not the email I am looking for. I've spend a lot of time even trying to grep with numbers and letters around @ but to no avail. Seems like a puzzle I cannot solve. :(

Can you give a second try in checking if you can find another email in this file ?